# Pprint within tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to find a way to show a list of titles, urls, and time stamps for a google search/RSS FEED that I'm working on for a GUI.  I'm having a lot of trouble trying to find a way to sort the results in a nice readable form.  Any articles or guidance as far as what to do would be greatly appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib.request
import feedparser
from pprint import pprint



search_term = ('') #search term for url
quoted_search_term = urllib.parse.quote(search_term) 
def go():
    text.delete(1.0, END) #delete text
    rss_string = 'https://news.google.com/news/section?output=rss'.format       (quoted_search_term)
    parsed_rss_string = feedparser.parse(rss_string) #assigning variable for  parsed feed
    text.insert(1.0, parsed_rss_string) #insert text of parsed feed 


browser_window = Tk() #tk window
browser_window.title('RSS Feed') #Window title
label = Label(browser_window, text= 'Search:') 
entry = Entry(browser_window)
button = Button(browser_window, text='Go', command = go)#Go Button 
text = Text(browser_window) #results box

label.pack(side=TOP) #Positioning of search title
entry.pack(side=TOP) #Positioning of search box
button.pack(side=TOP)#Positioning of go
text.pack(side= RIGHT) #Positioning of text
browser_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand what `pprint` has to do with it.You are writing to a textbox and not printing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prettified string, use `pprint.pformat`:

```
from pprint import pformat

...

def go():
    ...
    parsed = feedparser.parse(rss_string)
    prettified = pformat(parsed)
    text.insert("1.0", prettified)
```

NOTE:

- there's no placeholder in the url `https://news.google.com/news/section?output=rss`; no effect of `str.format`.
- feedparser.parse does not return a string, but a dictionary.

---

**UPDATE** to show publish date, title, url only, you need to get those entries from dictionaries:

```
def go():
    rss_string = 'https://news.google.com/news/section?output=rss'
    parsed = feedparser.parse(rss_string)
    text.delete("1.0", END)
    for entry in parsed['entries']:
        text.insert(END, '{0[published]} - {0[title]} {0[link]}\n\n'.format(entry))
```

Comment: Is there a way to just have the title of the article, url, and date without everything else or would I have to use the dict to get that?

Comment: @learningpython, I added another version of `go()` that shows date, title, url only.

Comment: I ended up working on it and got something very similar to your solution. Thank you for your help!